# QGIS print layout geo-pdf export: Flipped legend and symbology

Tags: qgis, print-composer, geopdf

[image][image]I have been using QGIS (currently 3.22 on Windows 11) for several years to produce maps that I export as geo-pdfs. I recently accidentally changed the page properties from A4 to A3 (and back again once I realized). Since then, all exported geo-pdfs to other devices have the legend mirrored, too small and in a completely different place than intended. Some symbology or labels show the same effect from time to time.

I've tried to create new print layouts, experimented with the pdf settings, transferred all layers to a new project, etc, etc.

It seems to be linked to the pdf conversion, as it shows all elements correctly when I transfer the pdf to my dropbox, but not when I use email, whatsapp, telegram, etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. To increase the chances of a helpful answer would you be able to share some screenshots showing what your pdfs look like? Are you using a layout template or importing items from another template? Have you also made sure that you've selected 'Resize layout' under the Layout Properties tab?

Comment: Thank you @she_weeds. I did add a screenshot now. I have selected "Resize layout" under the layout properties tab.

Comment: Okay, I haven't got a clue why you're experiencing these changes. I'm assuming you've used the same version of QGIS in between and haven't changed the print resolution under the Layout tab, Does the same thing happen if you export as a regular pdf (not geo-pdf?)

Comment: I found where the problem is: When I remove the road names (set the label settings of the layer to "no labels") then it works perfectly. I've tried "fix geometries" and to remove/add the layer again, but the problem persists. In the label settings I could not find any options that would solve the problem. I do need the road names on the map...